# Apache camel jetty RestletOperationException on invoking request 1001 when mocked restlet endpoint

Tags: java, mocking, apache-camel, embedded-jetty

This exception is common in cases when given service is not running. But this case is different:
I have camel route which I wrote integration tests for. Route itself was working in production-like environment, but in tests, mocked endpoint is not called and route fails with (shortened):

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractSessionInputBuffer.fillBuffer(AbstractSessionInputBuffer.java:160) ~[httpcore-4.4.1.jar:4.4.1]
    ...
    at org.restlet.ext.httpclient.internal.HttpMethodCall.sendRequest(HttpMethodCall.java:339) ~[org.restlet.ext.httpclient-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.ClientAdapter.commit(ClientAdapter.java:105) [org.restlet-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at org.restlet.engine.adapter.HttpClientHelper.handle(HttpClientHelper.java:119) [org.restlet-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at org.restlet.Client.handle(Client.java:153) [org.restlet-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at org.restlet.Restlet.handle(Restlet.java:275) [org.restlet-2.3.5.jar:na]
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:79) [camel-restlet-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_91]
15:35:38.913 [qtp995381766-39] WARN  o.e.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler - /data/v2/users/17
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:68) ~[camel-http-common-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.MessageSupport.getBody(MessageSupport.java:41) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.readRequest(DefaultHttpBinding.java:97) ~[camel-http-common-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    ..
Caused by: org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException: Early EOF
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput$3.noContent(HttpInput.java:506) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInput.read(HttpInput.java:124) ~[jetty-server-9.2.10.v20150310.jar:9.2.10.v20150310]
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:196) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copy(IOHelper.java:169) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(IOHelper.java:218) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.util.IOHelper.copyAndCloseInput(IOHelper.java:214) ~[camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpHelper.readResponseBodyFromInputStream(HttpHelper.java:244) ~[camel-http-common-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpHelper.readRequestBodyFromServletRequest(HttpHelper.java:195) ~[camel-http-common-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.DefaultHttpBinding.parseBody(DefaultHttpBinding.java:492) ~[camel-http-common-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpMessage.createBody(HttpMessage.java:66) ~[camel-http-common-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
15:35:38.949 [Restlet-167550865] ERROR o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-nb-mensik-61516-1466775296892-0-3 on ExchangeId: ID-nb-mensik-61516-1466775296892-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:9000/data/v2/users/17?projection=full with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTP/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server

org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking http://localhost:9000/data/v2/users/17?projection=full with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTP/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - The connector failed to complete the communication with the server
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.populateRestletProducerException(RestletProducer.java:232) ~[camel-restlet-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:84) ~[camel-restlet-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.process(RestletProducer.java:98) ~[camel-restlet-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:141) [camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:460) [camel-core-2.16.0.jar:2.16.0]
```

I was suprised that mock was listening and responding on given url: http://localhost:9000/data/v2/users/17?projection=full but it did not get any response during the tests.

More concrete description:
There are three modules (call them A, B and C) each running in its embedded jetty. I want to cover by integration tests module A and thus I needed to mock all calls from module A to modules B and C. I got correctly called mock of B, but mock C was not called and test failed with exception above. During tests endpoints mocked by C (which was not reachable by tests) were reachable by curl calls with same headers etc..

Answer (score 0):

This strange exception was triggered because I did not properly remove http headers using:  `.removeHeaders("org.restlet.http.headers") // remove HTTP headers from incoming request` 
in routes after rest calls to module B. 
I tried to add this remove headers to mocked response of module B (since removing headers is done in this module)

```
        authorizationServiceMock.whenExchangeReceived(1,
                    exchange -> {
                        assertEquals(exchange.getIn().getHeader(HTTP_PATH, String.class), "/authorization/Bearer MagicToken");
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, APPLICATION_JSON);
                        exchange.getIn().removeHeaders(ATTRIBUTE_HEADERS);
                        exchange.getIn().setBody(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(new UserToken("MagicToken", 17L)));
                    });
```

but it did not help.

So I had to modify "production route" of module A by this removal of headers after call to module B. Then mocked module C was called without problem.

...if only there were more informative exception thrown :(