# Exception communicating with endpoint

Tags: rest, apache-camel, restlet

I am implementing an application which would be exposed using RESTful web service. This application would firstly consume a RESTful web service to get the JSON file and would return this JSON file to the requestor (application which would consume my service). I am facing issues consuming the web service.

**ERROR:**

> org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletOperationException: Restlet operation failed invoking https:// <--url--> 
>      with statusCode: 1001 /n responseBody:HTTPS/1.1 - Communication Error (1001) - 
>      The connector failed to complete the communication with the server
>
> at org.apache.camel.component.restlet.RestletProducer.populateRestletProducerException(RestletProducer.java:233)

**CODE:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">
  <camelContext id="camelcontext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <restConfiguration component="restlet" port="9091"/>

    <rest path="/say">
        <get uri="/hello" consumes="application/json" produces="application/json">
            <to uri="direct:hello" />
        </get>
    </rest>

    <route>
        <from uri="direct:hello"/>
        <to uri="restlet:https:// <--URL--> ?restletMethod=POST" />
    </route>
</camelContext>
</beans>
```

Comment: Are you tied to using the Restlet component? Restlet is deprecated from Camel 3.x, so you might be better off using another component like `servlet` (for providing your REST service) and `http` (for consuming the external service).

Answer (score 0):

Maby incoming request has additional headers, for example as in this issue [Apache camel jetty RestletOperationException on invoking request 1001 when mocked restlet endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38015614/apache-camel-jetty-restletoperationexception-on-invoking-request-1001-when-mocke) ("org.restlet.http.headers"). You can check and remove unnecessary headers from the request. Also, error may occur while the response by the same reason, check our service for set headers.